# what happens if we 'put' and new value to an already existing key in the Linkedhashmap

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a fixed set of key value pairs with which I am initializing the `LinkedHashMap<String, Double>.`

Does the insertion order remain the same when I do a

```
LinkedHashMap.put(existingKey, newValue);
```

To be precise my question is, when we update a value for a key using the `put` method, is the order of initial insertion disturbed??

If so 1) why?
2) How can I prevent this to preserve the initial order of insertion?

I chose [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) because, I wanted a collection that supports a key value pair and maintains the the insertion order.

TIA

Answer (score 13):

From the class doc:

> Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key `k` is reinserted into a map `m` if `m.put(k, v)` is invoked when `m.containsKey(k)` would return `true` immediately prior to the invocation.)

Answer (score 1):

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally
>   the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

So, yes, keySet(), values(), and entrySet() (the three collection views mentioned) return values in the order the internal linked list uses. And yes, the JavaDoc for Map and LinkedHashMap guarantee it.